# when enter pressed for the first time one br is appending from next time 2brs is appending?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, editor, text-editor, rich-text-editor

How to make my cursor move one line downward on pressing enter and preventing default?

The code I used is below:

```
var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var newEle = document.createTextNode('\n');
docFragment.appendChild(newEle);
newEle = document.createElement('br');
docFragment.appendChild(newEle); 
var newEle = document.createTextNode('\n');
docFragment.appendChild(newEle);
newEle = document.createElement('br');
docFragment.appendChild(newEle);
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
range.deleteContents();
range.insertNode(docFragment); //create a new range 
range = document.createRange();
range.setStartAfter(newEle);
range.collapse(true);
var sel = window.getSelection() sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [ask] with [mcve]

Comment: Add the code in question, also add HTML

Comment: I have added the code to your question. You can add to your own question by using the [edit] button. To learn more about how to format questions on [SO] read [this help document](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken to think that it's about "lines". The standard behavior for pressing *Enter* in a contenteditable element is to create a new paragraph (`<p>`), or list item if you're in a list, etc.

The default spacing (margin) between paragraphs is one line high.

If you want linebreaks, you'll need to either use CSS to mark the container as `white-space: pre`, or intercept the keypress, cancel its default action, and insert a `br` element. I think the first option is much easier.

Alternatively, you can reduce the margin between paragraphs in the parent container.

Comment: im using this from redlining concept.i builded editor while sinking the redlining in my editor it is giving issues http://nytimes.github.io/ice/demo/

Comment: @amarabkrish It works fine, it just doesn't do what *you* want. I'm not paid to write the code for you, but I'll help more if you get started and update your question with how you tried to implement your desired behavior.

Comment: @tffy hi i found ur id as tffy@free.fr i mailed my app please look into it.

Comment: I will not "look into it". It's up to you to do that and post the relevant code right here in your question. If you do not understand my answer, then please say what you'd like me to clarify.

Comment: in the app on pressing enter the icedemo creates a new span tag.and based on span tag im created a new popup such that use can accept or reject the changes.now the problem raises if user writes 10 lines 10 popups are created and now i need to show all 10 lines info on a single popup such that user can approve or reject change in one command.to solve this problem i overrided enter key function.while doing so the enter is not working properly.enter behave awkwardly

Comment: if i press enter fr the first time new tag created from second time onwards it behaving properly.

Comment: @tffy please find the rar file i send and replay it will be helpful to me thank you all